# Write video in a memory stream using libav

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

I am successfully capturing video packets from the network using libav. Currently, I have an AVFormatContext object in which I can write the header, the packets, etc... The point is that I want to dump everything on this context into a file when required. What should I do ?

Thanks in advance,
Dídac Pérez

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to record the received packets so that it was a standard media file?